# Can't find Flutter Inspector / Toggle Debug Paint in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, flutter

Trying to find the option **Toggle Debug Paint** or **Flutter Inspector** with no success in VS Code.

I have Flutter and Dart extensions installed on version 2.24.0.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command "Flutter: Toggle Debug Paint" was replaced with "Flutter: Inspect Widget" in version [2.17.0](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-17/) but starting with version [2.24.0](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-24/) it was also replaced with **Dart DevTools** option which is the new and current feature for debugging and inspecting Dart/Flutter.

In the command palette:

```
>Dart: Open DevTools
```

Note that the debug session must be active in order for the option to be available:

[image]

Comment: It opens a blank browser window here.

Comment: You can also get the address of your app from vscode debug console. I mean the address which is required to first setup dart devtools.